# Combining multiple different flutter projects

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

So I have received a project which requires e-commerce, food ordering and car hailing services like Grab to be inside one app. I have delivered all these 3 apps in different projects before and for this new project I'm wondering whether it is possible to combine all my previous source code into one project, running on different dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create packages for all 3 modules (food, e-commerce, car-hailing services)

To create a Flutter package, use the `--template=package` flag with `flutter create`:

```
flutter create --template=package food
```

Folder Structure

```
lib
packages
  - food
  - e_commerce
  - car_hailing_service
```

Import this in the main module's `pubspec.yaml` file

```
dependencies:
flutter:
  sdk: flutter

# My Custom Packages
food:
  path: packages/food
e_commerce:
  path: packages/e_commerce
car_hailing_service:
  path: packages/car_hailing_service
```

If you have any common functionalities for all 3 packages then create a separate package for that also and import that common package for all 3 packages.

Refer to this [document](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) for creating flutter packages. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Or if you want separate examples and testing suites, move it up a level, and use `path: ../packages/food`.  You can also eventually publish one of the packages to pub if you want.

Comment: I've created modules for these three and have moved the project files into them. I can navigate to those project screens without any problem. However, the providers that are used in the projects don't seem working. Do I have to move all providers to the main.dart in parent lib folder?

Comment: Yes, if you want that provider for all 3 modules then move that provider to main module.

Comment: I'm happy to help! @emily

Comment: how navigation will work in such case ?

Comment: But if we made changes in the for ex. food package do it update it in the main project ? i dont think so .

Comment: Yes, it'll affect the main project too, coz you're dependent of food package @appdev

Comment: How to navigation different project depends on login